# Simulating an inner join with django's orm and no explicit foreign key

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two models, Widgets and Cases. There is no explicit relationship between the tables (no foreign keys). The tables contents look something like:

```
Widgets                              Cases                          
|----+--------+-------+---------|    |----+------+-------+---------|
| id | color  | spots | stripes |    | id | size | spots | stripes |
|----+--------+-------+---------|    |----+------+-------+---------|
|  1 | blue   |     2 |       6 |    |  1 | s    |     2 |       1 |
|  2 | blue   |     3 |      10 |    |  2 | m    |     2 |       6 |
|  3 | blue   |     2 |       1 |    |  3 | l    |     3 |      10 |
|  4 | green  |    20 |       7 |    |  4 | xl   |    20 |       7 |
|  5 | purple |     3 |      10 |    |----+------+-------+---------|
|----+--------+-------+---------|
```

I want to get all the cases that have the same number of spots and stripes as any one of the blue widgets. Using SQL, it would look like:

```
SELECT Cases.id
FROM Cases
    INNER JOIN Widgets 
    ON     Cases.spots = Widgets.spots 
       AND Cases.stripes = Widgets.stripes
WHERE Widgets.color = 'blue';
```

Which should return ids: `[1, 2, 3]`

I'm trying to get the same results using the django ORM. What I've come up with is:

```
selected_widgets = Widgets.objects.filter(color='blue').values('spots', 'stripes')
associated_cases = [Cases.objects.get(spots=v['spots'], stripes=v['stripes']) 
                        for v in selected_widgets]
```

Assume that `spots` and `stripes` will always uniquely identify a case, so the `.get` call is not a problem. This solution still seems very inefficient, making a separate call to the database for each widget, whereas the sql just makes an inner join. Is there a simple way to reduce the number of runs to the database while still using the django ORM?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a perfectly fine time to use the `.raw()` method; you can specify the exact SQL and get the result as a the normal Django result list of objects.